# Jquery Select box values using Struts2 UI tags

Tags: jquery, struts2, jquery-selectbox

In a jsp page i have a select Input which gets the values from a Struts2 action, and i am using Struts2 iterator tag to get the values.

```
<select id="package-type-input" name="packageTypeId">
    <gs:iterator var="package" value="" id="test-iterator">
       <option value='<gs:property value="#package.id"/>'  
       <gs:property value="#package.packagename"/></option>
    </gs:iterator>
</select>
```

I am getting values from the struts2 action as List packagesList. I am trying to add those values to the iterator using the below line. But its not working

```
$("#test-iterator").val(packageList).
```

The ajax call is

```
_getAccountDetails: function () {
    var self = this;
    var organizationId = self.id;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: self.url.getOrgPackageDetails,
        dataType: 'json',
        traditional: true,
        data: "organizationId=" + organizationId,
        success: function (response) {
            self._setData(response.data,response.packageList);
        },
        error: function (response) {}
    });
},
```

the response.packageList is the jsonified form of java Array list.
setData method sets the data from response.data into its respective fields.

```
_setData: function (data, packageList) {
    var self = this;
    self.dom.currentPackageType.val(data.CurrentPackage);
    self.dom.currentUsersLimit.val(data.Users);
    self.dom.currentEntityLimit.val(data.Entities);
    self.dom.CurrentRenewalDate.val(moment(data.RenewDate).calendar());
    self.dom.currentQEntityLimit.val(data.QEntity);
    self._bindGUIEvents()
},
```

Comment: i am confused why you doing this when S2 select tag has `listKey` and `listValue` properties defined for this

Comment: do u use this tag library ?? <%@taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>

Comment: Actually am getting the packageList data as response from an ajax call. so i want to set the packageList as value to the select tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it easily with s2 select tag, iterator tag is not required here

```
<gs:select
       id="package-type-input" 
       name="packageTypeId"
       list="packageList"
       listKey="id"
       listValue="packagename"
/>
```

Take a look at the [select tag description](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/select.html)

Also, follow the [Tag Reference](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/tag-reference.html) whenever you have a doubt.

As for your edited post:
In your `_setData` function

```
$.each(packageList, function(i,package){
    var option = $("<option value="+package.id+">"+package.packagename+"</option>");
    $("#package-type-input").append(option);
});
```

Comment: This one works for me..  But how if want to append the values that are returned from an ajax call.  say packageList is the list returned from an ajax call.. how am i going to put it in select box..  any help will be appreciated..

Comment: In which format are you returning the list from ajax call? Is it json or xml or some other format? It would be helpful if you post your ajax call code.